# Is it possible to append an object to a python 2D list and print it?

Tags: python, list, oop, append

Im creating a mini chess game, and for good practice, rather than do it procedurally, I wanted to do it in oop (python because Im lazy with syntax). I managed to created a class for the game board, as well as classes for pawns. The game board class has a method called *create_board*:

```py
def create_board(self, empty_cell, player_pawn, computer_pawn):        
    for row in range(self.size):
        if row == 0:
            self.board.append([computer_pawn] * self.size)
        if row == self.size - 1:
            self.board.append([player_pawn] * self.size)
        if row != 0 and row != self.size - 1:
            self.board.append([empty_cell] * self.size)
    return board
```

where *`computer_pawn`*, *`player_pawn`* and *`empty_cell`* are their own individual classes (right now they all look the same):

```
class player_pawn:

      #player_pawn constructor
      def __init__(self, value):
            self.value = value
```

The issue is my print method in the *game_board* class:

```
  def print_board(self):

        self.board_string = ""
        for row in range(self.size):
              for col in range(self.size):
                    self.board_string += str(self.board[row][col]) + "  "
              self.board_string += "\n"
        print self.board_string
```

instead of outputting a string of numbers in a square:

```
   "2  2  2
    0  0  0
    1  1  1"
```

it outputs:

> <**main**.computer_pawn instance at 0x107742cb0>  <**main**.computer_pawn instance at 0x107742cb0>
> <**main**.computer_pawn instance at 0x107742cb0>
> <**main**.empty_cell instance at 0x107742c20>  <**main**.empty_cell instance at 0x107742c20>  <**main**.empty_cell
> instance at 0x107742c20>
> <**main**.player_pawn instance at 0x107742c68>  <**main**.player_pawn instance at 0x107742c68>  <**main**.player_pawn
> instance at 0x107742c68>

for reference, my current method calls and object creation looks like this:

```
board = game_board(3)
board.create_board(empty_cell(0), player_pawn(1), computer_pawn(2))
board.print_board()
```

Im trying to make it output the string style, so does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: define `__str__(self)` method for all the mentioned classes that returns the representation you want.

Comment: Use `self.board[row][col].value`

Comment: `print self.board_string`: don't use Python 2. Use a recent Python 3 to (learn to) code in, otherwise you'll run into issues in the (near) future.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and try to ask the question that you actually have. Clearly, the list contains the objects; they just don't look right when printing. So the title is wrong.